# What primary key to set on local android db before syncing it to server?

Tags: android, database, synchronization, realm

I am making an app which have a database model:

```
Item (int id, String name, String description, Date updatedDate, boolean isSynced)
```

The `id` of the `Item` is it's primary key (on local as well as server) and 
`id` is automatically generated on the server mysql db. I'm using realm to store `Items` on android device.

User can create and edit `Items` on device with/without internet. DB is synced when internet connection is available.

So when the User saves a new `Item`, then what `id` should I save it with on the local db so that syncing it with server doesn't cause problems

**Example**:

John have 3 `Items` on his **Moto X** as well as **Samsung S6** and both phones are synced to server.

He puts **Moto X** on airplane mode and adds an `Item` on **Samsung S6** which gets synced to server.

Now, **S6** has Items with ids -> 1,2,3,4

and **Moto X** has Items with ids -> 1,2,3

When Moto X will connect to internet, then it'll download the `Item` with `id`=4 but it's still on airplane mode.

While Moto X is still offline, John adds an `Item` on it. What id should I give to this new `Item` on local db, so that it doesn't cause any problem when **Moto X** is synced? John should be able to edit this new `Item` on the offline **Moto X**, so id can't be kept empty.

Thank You

Comment: each time when you add item from any device from server return its primary key/ unique id and update the added item with response id..\

Comment: yes off course you can edit offline via local primary key add one more coloum as server primary key update that new coloum with server primary key

Comment: Or you can setup some rules for the id. Like id of items created in local starts at 0xF0000000 (Only be meaningful for that device), and after sync with server, the id will be assigned by the server to something like 0x00000012 (Used globally by all the devices/server). Then the temporary used in the local before could just be dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just spitballing...

Add an `int local_id` and `int device_id` to the Item class. Every device that interacts with the server will get a unique and persistent device_id. When an Item is created on a device absent an internet connection, the device can refer to the local_id if the item needs to be edited. When the device is connected and an Item (!isSynced && id == null), send the Item to the DB for an insert operation, and then find the primary key of the newly inserted DB row by searching for local_id and device_id. The primary key value is sent back to the device, and the Item's primary key on the server is set as the `id` on the local copy of Item and set isSynced to true.

ETA: When retrieving Items from the db server that were created on other devices, you would need omit the foreign `local_id` when putting these Items into the device's table.

ETA2: And you would need to change the table setup on your devices so that `local_id` was the primary key and `id` was UNIQUE. But of course `id` remains the primary key on table on the db server.